# Wild animal in Virginia that sounds like monkey cackling/laughing?

Tags: united-states, animal-identification

I'm here hunting turkey in Virginia and I keep hearing unidentifiable sounds that I'm pretty sure are not turkey.

One of the most common one is something like a monkey (chimp) cackling/laughing. It's usually 16 equally pitched notes in a 4/4 beat: ka-ka-ka-ka times 4. It's probably a bird.

Do you know what animal this could be? Can you provide links to examples of the sound?

Comment: Sounds like a Sasquatch or Bigfoot to me.

Comment: What time of the day was it? I'm super inclined to call it a barred owl. But i'm not sure if a barred owl would sing during the day.

Comment: https://youtu.be/rYH34K6cPX0?t=59 Check this out. If this is what you heard, it's a barred owl. They sound pretty much like monkeys. And since you are from the Eastern US, it matches the description. I'll add it as an answer if this is the one. Else, the detective work continues :D

Comment: I have edited to correct location: mid-Atlantic is very much in the ocean :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_(United_States)

Comment: Yup - but it makes no sense to non-USA-ians. Mid Atlantic more accurately (and generally for other cultures) refers to that region centred on the middle of the Atlantic Ocean.

Comment: Is the pitch high? Some animals have patterns you describe but are lower pitched. Is there any space between each group of 4 beats, or after 16? Time of day can be important. When do you hear it? What type of region, like fields; some trees; heavy woods; near water? Do you have the usual group of [Virginia birds](http://www.pwconserve.org/wildlife/birds/index.html) at this time of year? Are there chipmunks and squirrels around? Breeding/migration make identification more difficult in this season. Any details will help, unless you've gotten a correct answer already! Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/TdkhMZZvdgc?t=112) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaAKBnxhw00) provide a possible cackling vocalisation by the barred owl.

Answer (score 5):

Grey squirrels make a surprising range of sounds, including quite a loud one sometimes called barking, but repetitive and rather like a cackling at times. [This video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhf72o0L8cw) collects a few of them; you might want to skip to about [3:40](https://youtu.be/Uhf72o0L8cw?t=219).

Your [Eastern Gray Squirrel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_gray_squirrel) is the same species as we have (introduced) in the UK. They make these alarm calls from in trees (sometimes high and not easily seen) so give the impression of birds until you catch them in the act.

Comment: I am so glad you brought up the Gray Squirrel...I am in the west with these beautiful blue grey squirrels.  They are worse than ravens or dogs barking...how they sustain their incessant 'barking' is amazing.  I just have to go out and shoo shoo the cat population to get them to stop.  Ravens do regimented series of 'barks' or 'caws'...its actually mathematical...amazing birds that are able to mimic the call of wolves to get the wolves ripping up a carcass so the ravens as well as Turkey Vultures can carry away chunks of food.  I've also know the cougar having a weird high pitched 'bark'.

Comment: Grins..wilderness and botany and biology are well known to me...I've spent more time in the wilderness than I have in square buildings.  Are fisherpeople on here or is there another spot for people who know rivers and fish?  Thanks, Sue.;

Comment: @stormy you'll find a lot of fishing related questions and activities on here. [Check these out](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing)

Comment: I think it might be it but not exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to the sounds/songs/calls on these two pages.

I would bet on the second one bird. But, the first one is worth listening to.

The first one on this page labeled "song":
https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Northern_Flicker/sounds

The first two on this page labeled "Wuk":
https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Pileated_Woodpecker/sounds

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the flicker or pileated per user14513. If not, have you considered the yellow billed cuckoo?
https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Yellow-billed_Cuckoo

Answer (score 0):

I would vote woodpecker, specifically the big red headed ones that we call "wood hens" here in alabama.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNVGPmo1xuA

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but this sounds like a woodpecker to me. That's how I describe the calls of a Pileated woodpecker here in Florida, like a monkey cackling/laughing. Check out the songs and calls on this page:
https://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/pileated-woodpecker

Comment: That answer has already been given, although this is a different link to evidence.